# JSON keep one line out of n

Tags: javascript, json

I want to display curves of data in JSON format using `flot.js` but the data file contains two many lines (over than 50,000) and it takes too much time to render the graph. So I would like to **keep only one line out of n**.

For example for n=3, I want to keep lines with indexes : 1,4,7,10 etc

The JSON data file has the following format :

```
[{"t":"22.40",
"lumi":"738.00",
"h":"31.20",
"f":"72.32",
"hi":"76.43",
"date":"2015-02-28T13:38:41.025Z",
"_id":"54f1c4e17cb06e5e09015b63"},

... 50,000 other lines
```

What is the simplest way to achieve this ?

Comment: `var arrData = JSON.parse(jsonData);`, `arrData[0]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove specific element from an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-specific-element-from-an-array)

Comment: No actually I want to delete for example lines with index 1,2,4,5,7,8 etc to only keep 1/3 of the lines. I will edit my post to make it clearer.

Comment: Are you pulling data from server side? If so the easy place would to filter it on the server side call with a query variable.

Comment: Yeah I'm pulling data from server side, but I use monk for that and I am not very familiar with it yet. Currently I'm using this piece of code to send it :     
`router.get('/sensors/get-sensors-data', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('sensorsCollection');
    collection.find({}, {sort: {date: -1}, limit: 3000}, function(e, docs){
        if (e) return next(e);
        res.send(docs);
    });
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to use `Array.filter()`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

to compact your array by removing rows every n, create this

```
Array.prototype.oneOutOf= function(n) {
  return this.filter(function(element,index) { 
    return (index%n)==0
  });
}
```

and then try

```
JSON.parse(jsondata).oneOutOf(10);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  I have trouble using JSON.parse though. It doesn't seem to  work well with the structure of my data file (see original post). In addition I need to keep the JSON format to send it to `flot.js`. Could you complete your answer accordingly ?

Comment: accept this answer and post another question specific to your problem about JSON parser